# Is there a way to separate frontend and backend on different servers

Tags: laravel

The project is based on Laravel 5.6.

I have a dilema with two options, but I'm not sure if the first one it can be possible to be applied.

1. For client side I have simple contact form which insert new record into database on submit. On the other hand I will have backend (interface) for reading, deleting these record and a lot of other things, but I need to be on different server with different domain name.
   Both shares the same code and database. I think about this by security reason.

Example: 
domain1.com referers to the contact form, but
domain2.com referers to the dashboard

Is that possible?

2. Or if point 1 is not possible - just single php file with that form to push the data into database. And on the other server will be the Laravel backend part.

I know that option 2 it can be perfect, but I'm interesting if is possible to separate two different parts which shares the same code based in Laravel or another kind of application.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need two installs of Laravel on different servers? Or do you just need two domains?  You can easily serve content to two domains using one Laravel app.  And security is not an issue if you set up your authentication and build your app properly.  Two apps with the same code is a headache to manage.

Comment: If you just need the form to send to Laravel you could post it via an API route or even embed the form in your site using an iFrame of your Laravel app.

Comment: Iframe and two Laravel apps are not an options for me, because I can have 5 domains with contact form and only one backend

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we do something similar. Essentially, you would set up your own backend API. Laravel has some things out of the box for this. Your frontend can be entirely generated by a frontend framework if you want- that's not an issue.

It makes API calls to your other domain to get data only, not views. The data is usually returned as JSON and then your JS can utilize it however you want!

Comment: Yes, maybe the API is an option to prepare the requests, something like a bridge between these two parts.

Comment: When someone builds a frontend and backend that are very separate from each other, they typically 'consume' their own API anyways. That's the term. Yours would just be slightly different because you wouldn't be using it locally, but from any other server.